# What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field?

Tags: java, variables, scope

What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field with respect to a simple Java program?

Comment: Maybe he is trying to learn how to program in Java, and has come across these terms that he is unsure of.

Comment: Tom is correct. I am a college student studying for a final I am not confident about.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A **local variable** is defined within the scope of a block.  It cannot be used outside of that block.

Example:

```
if(x > 10) {
    String local = "Local value";
}
```

I cannot use `local` outside of that `if` block.

An **instance field**, or **field**, is a variable that's bound to the object itself.  I can use it in the object without the need to use accessors, and any method contained within the object may use it.

If I wanted to use it *outside* of the object, and it was not `public`, I would have to use getters and/or setters.

Example:

```
public class Point {
    private int xValue; // xValue is a field

    public void showX() {
        System.out.println("X is: " + xValue);
    }
}
```

An **input parameter**, or **parameter** or even **argument**, is something that we pass into a method or constructor.  It has scope with respect to the method or constructor that we pass it into.

Example:

```
public class Point {
    private int xValue;
    public Point(int x) {
        xValue = x;
   }

    public void setX(int x) {
        xValue = x;
    }
}
```

Both `x` parameters are bound to different scopes.

A **class field**, or **static field**, is similar to a field, but the difference is that you do not need to have an instance of the containing object to use it.

Example:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

I don't need an instance of `Integer` to retrieve the globally known maximum value of all ints.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a **parameter** is a variable within the _definition_ of a method. An **argument** would be the _data_ or _actual value_ which is passed to the method.


**An example of parameter usage:**


`int numberAdder(first,second)`


**An example of argument usage:**


`numberAdder(4,2)`

Answer (score 5):

Not quite.

A class field is what you think a local variable is but it is generally a static field and so is the same across all instances.

An instance field is the same as a class field, but is non static and can be different for each instance of the object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

And a local variable is a variable inside a method or block, that can only be used by that method or block.

Oh and your input parameter definition is correct, an input parameter is a field that is passed to a method as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A class field is often called a class variable, and you can find that information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a read through [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

> I know the local variable is a variable that is available to the class it is in, correct?

No, generally a local variable refers to a variable that only has context within the area it was declared.  This typically refers to variables declared within methods and `{...}` blocks (like `if` statements)

> An instance field is an Object that is created in the constructor...?

Not really, an instance field is any field, declared at the class level which is not static, therefore it's value only has meaning to an individual instance of the class

> An input parameter is what is passed into a method.

Yes

> But I have NO idea about a class field!

A class field and instance field are (generally) the same thing.  The only difference would be if the field is declared `static`, then it can't be a instance field...

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is local to a method.

An instance fields is the field of an instance of a class i.e. an object.

A parameter is passed to a method

A class field, I assume is a static field which is associated with the class. e.g. if you use multiple class loaders, you can have multiple classes with the same name and their own static fields.

Answer (score 1):

A **local variable** is a variable in a method. It's scope is limited to the scope of the two parenthesis around it. {}

Example:

```
public void someMethod () {

    int localVariable1 = 5;

    if (...) { 
        int localVariable2 = 7;
    }
}
```

With an **instance field**, I think you mean a member of a a class instance. If you take for example the class `Dimension`, this would be `height` or `width`.
.
An **input parameter** is a parameter in a method, as you guessed.

A **class field** is a field in a static method.