# java.lang.NullPointerException Main.java:6

Tags: java

I have two classes

I am not sure why this is erroring. In eclipse there are no red underlines.

Main:

```
package com.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Week myWeek = new Week(Week.days.FRIDAY);
        System.out.println(myWeek.Today.toString());
    }
}
```

Week:

```
package com.example;

public class Week {
    public static enum days {
        SUNDAY,
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY
    }

    static final days[] order = {
        days.SUNDAY, days.MONDAY, days.TUESDAY, days.WEDNESDAY, 
        days.THURSDAY, days.FRIDAY, days.SATURDAY
    };
    days Today;

    Week(days toSetTo){
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        days Today = toSetTo;
    }
}
```

the error is on Main.java:6

Comment: where is the variable in the constructor stored?

Comment: Now is the time to start using Java code conventions; they make communication much simpler. Capitalize classes (including enums), constants in `ALL_CAPS`, variables in `camelCase`.

Comment: You are declaring two variables for `Today`, one variable is local to the constructor, and the other is the instance variable. You should always use `this.varName` to reference an instance variable.

Comment: Proper dupe: [Why does Java throw NullPointerException here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30567802)

Answer (score 1):

The following is failing at runtime:

`myWeek.Today.toString()`

because `myWeek.Today` is null.

In your constructor instead of:

`days Today = toSetTo;`

you need to do this:

`Today = toSetTo;`

Answer (score 0):

You should have fixed the `unused` warning properly instead of suppressing it. Remove the word `days` in that line. And look closely at the colors of the variables in Eclipse. They tell you which names belong to each other.