# Why can't I use this variable

Tags: java

I am trying to use a number (1/2/3) the user inputs to control something. When I try to use converted choice it says cannot find symbol. Why is this?

```
// Start user input //
    public static int userChoice() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = userInput.nextLine();
        int convertedChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        return convertedChoice;
    }
    // End user input //

    // Start scan maze //
    static void whatMaze() {
        if (convertedChoice == 1) {
            System.out.println("you chose 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you chose something else");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've defined `convertedChoice` inside the `userChoice()` method, you can't use it from `whatMaze()`.

Comment: I thought me setting userChoice to public and returning convertedChoice would allow me to do this?

Comment: userChoice is a method, so it being public will only allow you to call it from anywhere. You either need to return your value from that method or put all of these methods in a class with a choice attribute. I recommend the former.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671008/what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-variable-an-instance-field-an-input-par)

Comment: thanks @abalos I now get the method is public and not the variable.

In terms of returning the value in the method is that not what "return convertedChoice;" does?

Thanks

Comment: You need to update your whatMaze() function to include the return value from userChoice(). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `userChoice()`, and use the output, since the variable `convertedChoice` is only in scope (declared) in the method.

e.g.

```
 if (userChoice() == 1) {
       System.out.println("you chose 1");
 } else {
      System.out.println("you chose something else");
 }
```

You *could* declare convertedChoice as a member in your class, but I wouldn't do that since in more complex scenarios it leads you open to shared-state/threading problems etc.

Answer (score 1):

`convertedChoice` is local to `userChoice` meaning you can't access it outside that method.

You probably meant to *call* `userChoice` to use the returned value:

```
if (userChoice() == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the value of convertedChoice as parameter to your function

```
// Start user input //
    public static int userChoice() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = userInput.nextLine();
        int convertedChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        return convertedChoice;
    }
    // End user input //

    // Start scan maze //
    static void whatMaze(int convertedChoice) {
        if (convertedChoice == 1) {
            System.out.println("you chose 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you chose something else");
        }
    }
```

In your main function (or wherever you use it):

```
whatMaze(userChoice());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          int choice = userChoice();
          whatMaze(choice);
    }


    // Start user input //
    public static int userChoice() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = userInput.nextLine();
        int convertedChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        return convertedChoice;
    }
    // End user input //

    // Start scan maze //
    static void whatMaze(int convertedChoice) {
        if (convertedChoice == 1) {
            System.out.println("you chose 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you chose something else");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start user input //
    public static int userChoice() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = userInput.nextLine();
        int convertedChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        return convertedChoice;
    }
    // End user input //

    // Start scan maze //
    static void whatMaze() {
        if (userChoice() == 1) {
            System.out.println("you chose 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you chose something else");
        }
    }
```