# Accessing a static array from a method in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following static method in my main class:

```
static int daysMonth(int Y, int M){
    int [] month = {31, 28+(Y%4==0?1:0), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    return month[M-1];
}
```

I want to access the month array from a different method that I am creating lower in the class.  I want the variable D (which will stand for days) to take the exact value of the M-1 index, but I am not sure how to access it correctly...I know this is probably a very simple thing, but I can't recall how it should be done, recommendations on things I should re-read (regarding arrays or smth in Java) are welcome!

Comment: month is a local variable and its not static. If you want to access it in other methods you have to declare it outside of any method as a field of a class, or make sure you pass the local variable to wherever you need it. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671008/what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-variable-an-instance-field-an-input-par

Comment: I think you need to call the method from another class as you have given description you need to assign value to variable D on the basis of passed value of M from another class. So here you can make you method public and import the class to use the method.

Comment: Its java. Make it an own class. And pass the instance through your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array outside of the method, then you can use it in the entire class.

```
static int [] month = null;

static int daysMonth(int Y, int M){
    month = {31, 28+(Y%4==0?1:0), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    return month[M-1];
}
```

Comment: So If i leave it outside of the method, should I access it this way?
D = month[M-1]; ?

Comment: Yes you can. Altough i would recommend you read about how constructors and encapsulation works, as it is not the best practice to use static operators everywhere.