# ActionListener Added to JButton but Doesn't Work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, keylistener

The user must enter the numbers in a text field. When the user presses Enter key, the number should be deleted from the text field and added to ArrayList.When the user clicks on Calculate button, the program must calculate the result and project it to the second text field.When the user clicks on Reset button, the texts on text fields must be deleted and the ArrayList must be cleared.
I added ActionListener to btnCalc, but when I clicked them, there is no change on TextField

```
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

  public class AddMult extends JFrame implements KeyListener,     ActionListener{

private JLabel lblEnterNum;
private JTextField txtEnterNum;
private JRadioButton radBtnAdd;
private JRadioButton radBtnMul;
private JButton btnCalc;
private JButton btnReset;
private JLabel lblResult;
private JTextField txtResult;







public AddMult() {
    setSize(300, 300);



    lblEnterNum=new JLabel();
    lblEnterNum.setText("Enter a number:");

    lblEnterNum.setSize(100,20);
    lblEnterNum.setLocation(100, 20);
    add(lblEnterNum);
    lblEnterNum.setVisible(true);


    txtEnterNum = new JTextField();
    txtEnterNum.setSize(90,20);
    txtEnterNum.setLocation(105, 60);
    add(txtEnterNum);
    txtEnterNum.setVisible(true);
    txtEnterNum.addKeyListener(this);


    JRadioButton radBtnAdd = new JRadioButton();
    radBtnAdd.setText("Add");
    radBtnAdd.setSize(70,50);
    radBtnAdd.setLocation(80, 80);
    radBtnAdd.setSelected(true);
    add(radBtnAdd);


    JRadioButton radBtnMul = new JRadioButton();
    radBtnMul.setText("Multiply");
    radBtnMul.setSize(100,50);
    radBtnMul.setLocation(160, 80);
    add(radBtnMul);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(radBtnAdd);
    group.add(radBtnMul);

    btnCalc= new JButton();
    btnCalc.setText("Calculate");
    btnCalc.setLocation(70, 140);
    btnCalc.setSize(80, 40);
    add(btnCalc);


    btnReset=new JButton();
    btnReset.setText("Reset");
    btnReset.setLocation(180, 140);
    btnReset.setSize(60, 40);
    add(btnReset);


    JLabel lblResult =new JLabel();
    lblResult.setText("Result:");
    lblResult.setLocation(95, 200);
    lblResult.setSize(70, 40);
    add(lblResult);


    JTextField txtResult = new JTextField();
    txtResult.setLocation(150, 205);
    txtResult.setSize(70,30);
    txtResult.setEditable(false);
    add(txtResult);

    btnCalc.addActionListener(this);
    btnReset.addActionListener(this);

    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);



    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
AddMult test = new AddMult();
}
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void addList() {

    int num = Integer.parseInt(txtEnterNum.getText().trim());
    list.add(num);
    txtEnterNum.setText("");


}

public String sum() {
    int total=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        total=total+list.get(i);
    }
    return total + "";
}

public String mult() {
    int mult=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        mult=mult*list.get(i);
    }
    return mult+"";
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sum =sum();
    String mult=mult();

    if(btnCalc.equals(a.getSource())) {
    if (radBtnAdd.isSelected()) {

        txtResult.setText(sum);
    }
    else if (radBtnMul.isSelected()) {

        txtResult.setText(mult);
    }


    }
    else if (btnReset.equals(a.getSource())) {
        txtEnterNum.setText("");
        txtResult.setText("");
        list.clear();
    }

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_ENTER) {
        addList();
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_ESCAPE)
        System.exit(1);
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671008/what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-variable-an-instance-field-an-input-par)

Answer (score 0):

Because you create btnCalc twice.
Please reemove this code:

```
JButton btnCalc = new JButton();
```

and write:

```
private JButton btnCalc = new JButton();
```

After that:

```
btnCalc.equals(a.getSource())
```

will return true.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize btnCalc and btnReset, don't redeclare them like:

```
JButton button;

void foo(){
    JButton button = new JButton();
 }
```

But rather like this:

```
JButton button;

void foo(){
    button = new JButton();
 }
```

Also, in your action listener, don't test for the name of the button as a string but test the button to be equal to the object:

```
actionEvent.getSource().equals(btnReset);
```

Comment: Sorry I whipped this up on mobile.