# Passing variable as method argument

Tags: java, linked-list, method-call

I'm working on a linked list code and wanted to access head.next.next.data. Is there a means where I can store .next.next.data to a variable x so that I can make the call head.x and retrieve the result provided I have data populated in the list? I want to implement

```
public class CustomSOL<E> implements SOL<E>  
{
    private static class customNode<E>
    {
        private customNode<E> next;
        private E data;

        public customNode(E dataItem)
        {
            this.data = dataItem;
            this.next = null;
        }

        private customNode(E dataItem, customNode<E> nodeRef)
        {
            this.data = dataItem;
            this.next = nodeRef;
        }
    }

    private customNode<E> head;
    private int size;

    public CustomSOL()
    {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }


    public void solLookup(int amount)
    {
        String s = "next";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(14);
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            sb.append(".").append(s);

        System.out.println(head.s.data);
    }
}
```

so in main if I have

```
        CustomSOL<String> list = new CustomSOL<String>();
        list.solAdd("Apple");
        list.solAdd("Orange");
        list.solAdd("Banana");
        list.solAdd("Strawberry");
        list.solAdd("Papaya");
```

and I call list.solLookup(3):

```java
String s = "next.next.next";   
System.out.println(head.s.data);
```

I want to see **Strawberry** printed out, which it obviously won't because s is string. But is there a way, just like how javascript and PHP have variable functions, to replace all those next calls with a variable s? I'm using a string because I can use the amount parameter in solLookup to create the appropriate next call notations. Thank you!

Comment: What  `head` implementation is?

Comment: head is a pointer to the first node in the linked list.

Comment: There is no pointers in Java. What type of `head` is?

Comment: I know, head is a node (but when you learn linked lists it is drawn at the beginning like a pointer. Have you worked with linked lists before?

Comment: As I understand your question, with this code you want to print in console field of object `head` called `x`. You misunderstanding whole concept of OOP. See the difference between local variables and fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671008/what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-variable-an-instance-field-an-input-par

Comment: I'm implementing a custom generic-type single linked list (not Java's double linked list). So if my linked list has {"a","b","c"}, head.next.data should give me a "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head.next.next.data` is (presumably) a reference to some data.  The Java compiler turns that phrase into executable code to fetch the data you want.

`".next.next.data"` is just a sequence of Unicode characters in the program, whether literally presented or built at runtime.  It is not (in simple programming) possible to turn that into a runtime reference to some data that just happens to be named similarly to the characters in the string.   Doing that is a job for a Java compiler, and the compiler has finished its job before your program runs.

There are advanced techniques ("reflection") but I would not recommend them to you at what I assume to be your level of expertise.

To get the k'th level object you simply iterate down the list 'k' times:

```
public Node get(int k) {
    Node n = head;
    while (k > 0) {
       n = n.next;  // or n.next() if need be
       k--;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This is simpler than building a string with 'k' occurrences of 'next'.

Answer (score 0):

Assume such implementation of linked list:

```java
class List<T> {
    static class Head<T> {
        public T value;
        public Head<T> next;

        public Head(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public Head<T> head;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```java
List<String> list = new List<>();

list.head = new List.Head<>("a");
list.head.next = new List.Head<>("b");

System.out.println(list.head.next.value);
```

There is many ways how you can improve this, but you get the idea.