# When we create a setter method in java , how does java know to which variable we want to set the given value from the setter ? read discription please

Tags: java, getter, setter

In my given Image you can see that I have created a Class named employee with one variable with no assigned value.Also I have given getter and setter methods. Now the queston i have is that , in the Setter method i.e (setsalary) ,  I am taking a integer value into the variable s and then assigning it to the salary variable. Now when I create an object of that particular class ( as you can see in the image), how does the program knows that the given value of salary has to be assigned to the salary of the object i.e (John.salary) , I mean i have only written salary=s; and nothing else. How does the program setts the value exactly to the object ?

[image]

Comment: _..I mean i have only written salary=s.._ False, you have declared `salary` as a class property and then assigned a value to it. I recommend to read over basics of OOP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671008/what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-variable-an-instance-field-an-input-par)

Answer (score 1):

> how does the program knows that the given value of salary has to be
>   assigned to the salary of the object i.e (John.salary) , I mean i have
>   only written salary=s; and nothing else

The missing ingredient is the [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

What isn't written there is that the `this` keyword is OPTIONAL, thus this line:

```
salary=s;
```

and this line are equivalent:

```
this.salary=s;
```

So it knows which instance (John in this case) to use because there is actually an invisible "this" in front of "salary" telling it to assign to the CURRENT OBJECT.